# Beautiful Soup Links - href returns no results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink, tags

I am trying to retrieve only the links on the following page for the companies:
https://clutch.co/it-services/msp

It appears this is a common question and I have spent the day reviewing other posts, but I have not had any success.

Code:

```
links = []
for l in soup.find_all(class_='website-link website-link-a'):
    results = (l.get('href'))
    links.append(results)

print(links)
```

Output:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

When I print just the results of `soup.find_all` I get:

```
<a data-extlink-pid="1219089" href="https://fulcrumdigital.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<i class="icon icon-visit-site"></i><span class="">Visit Website</span>
</a>
</li>, etc, etc,
```

I need to extract just after the href but cannot figure out how. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i tried to recap your question - and runned the code you were provided - but on Colab - it turns out to give no results at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `'.website-link-a > a'` (select every `<a>` tag directly under tag with `class="website-link-a"`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://clutch.co/it-services/msp'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.website-link-a > a'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
http://electric.ai/
http://www.symphony-solutions.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp
https://www.bairesdev.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=msp
https://www.helixstorm.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp
http://www.sundevs.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp
http://www.computersolutionseast.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp
/your-project
http://techmd.com
http://www.sugarshot.io/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=directory
https://www.empist.com?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
http://www.frameworkIT.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
https://www.clickittech.com/
https://cyberduo.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp
http://www.realnets.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
https://www.ibexlabs.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
https://bianor.com/
http://www.endpoint.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
https://devopsprodigy.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=directory
https://vrpconsulting.com/
https://siliconreef.co.uk/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral
http://www.agencypartner.com?utm_source=clutch&utm_medium=profile&utm_campaign=directory_listing
```

Comment: good day dear Andrej - awesome:  you offer a great approach - and your ideas are just great - (as usually : i have seen a whole lot of great solutions you provided. ) but this does not work for me.  I am willing to get the data out of clutch.co - with as most as we can get ouf of the pages. But i tried several steps and nothing worked correct for me. 
Perhalps you can provied a approach  that works. Loook forward to hear from you Regards.  btw: see my trial here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389587/my-method-bs4-request-pnada-need-a-workaround-with-alternat-method
 regards malaga

Answer (score 1):

You need some changes into `find_all` method. You should use `soup.find_all('li',class_='website-link website-link-a')` instead of `soup.find_all(class_='website-link website-link-a')`. you need to changes `l.a.get('href')` instead of `l.get('href')`. Then you get your actual result. You can try to get links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://clutch.co/it-services/msp'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

links = []
for l in soup.find_all('li',class_='website-link website-link-a'):
    results = (l.a.get('href'))
    links.append(results)

print(links)
```

Output will be:

```
['http://electric.ai/', 'http://www.symphony-solutions.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp', 'https://www.bairesdev.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=msp', 'https://www.helixstorm.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp', 'http://www.sundevs.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp', 'http://www.computersolutionseast.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp', 'http://techmd.com', 'http://www.sugarshot.io/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=directory', 'https://www.empist.com?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'http://www.frameworkIT.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'https://www.clickittech.com/', 'https://cyberduo.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=it-services-msp', 'http://www.realnets.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'https://www.ibexlabs.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'https://bianor.com/', 'http://www.endpoint.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'https://devopsprodigy.com/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=directory', 'https://vrpconsulting.com/', 'https://siliconreef.co.uk/?utm_source=clutch.co&utm_medium=referral', 'http://www.agencypartner.com?utm_source=clutch&utm_medium=profile&utm_campaign=directory_listing']
```

Comment: many thanks for steppin up the plate - this solution looks awesome!